# Can outfits other than Law Dogs start with Gomorra Jail?

Tags: doomtown-reloaded

[Gomorra Jail](http://dtdb.co/en/card/06011) is a deed with the following text:

> You may start with this deed in play in place of a Law Dogs dude.
>
> **Controller React, Boot:** When another player's wanted dude is discarded during the High Noon phase, this deed gains a permanent control point.

You can have dudes from other outfits in your deck (potentially with an additional upkeep cost, pg. 16), so is there any reason another faction, like the Sloane Gang, can't start with Gomorra Jail? I mean, could they just start with three Sloane Gang characters and have the Gomorra Jail be a "different outfit" dude from the Law Dogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the rulebook, page 14:

> Once players have revealed their outfits, they search their decks for up to
>   five dudes—**either from their outfit or drifters**

(Bold added)

Dudes from other factions can be in your deck, but not your starting posse. Hence if you are playing something other than Law Dogs, there is no way to have a Law Dog in your posse for the Jail to start "in place of".